# Convert oracle query to HQL by using subquery

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql

I'm really confusing about sub Query of hibernate.

I've standard oracle query but unable to convert it into HQL.

```
select distinct b.nameId
from
(
select nameId from seg_user where id=1
)a, seg_user b
where b.id=a.nameId
```

can somebody convert it to HQL by using SubQuery or Crieteria

Comment: We need to see your entities to create a HQL query.

Comment: @Pablo can consider as same as I put in the query

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct b.nameId
from seg_user b
where b.id = some (
    select a.nameId from seg_user a where a.id=1
)
```

You can see how to use subqueries here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries